# Autowiring an interface implementation from an external library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, module

I have written a common library for future SpringBoot applications and made it into a `jar`. Inside, there is a service that autowires an interface:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    protected @Autowired AbstractUserService abstractUserService;
}
```

```
public interface AbstractUserService {
    Optional<? extends AbstractUser> findByPrincipal(Principal principal);
}
```

In my main application, in `build.gradle` I load the library mentioned above as follows:

```
...
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "$rootDir/libs"
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation name: "my-library"
    ...
}
```

Then I have implemented the interface:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements AbstractUserService {
    @Override public Optional<? extends AbstractUser> findByPrincipal(Principal principal) {
        // do something
    }
```

However, it seems that the library is unable to find it and I get the following exception:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in MyService required a bean of type 'AbstractUserService' that could not be found.
```

In my main application I have also added the following annotation in order to `@Autowire` the services exposed by this library:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"the.root.package.of.my-library"})
```

Is there something that can be done? Also, is there a better way of autowiring the exposed services without the explicit `scanBasePackage` description?

Comment: is package of `UserService ` included in `ComponentScan` ?

Comment: It's included in the main application. In the external library it is not. If I would include it, then I would have to recompile this library for every project I intend to use it for.

Comment: Have you tried to create the `UserService` from `@Bean` in your app instead of scanning? Might be some ordering issue here.

Comment: @grekier I have fixed it. Apparently after hours of trying, just minutes after posting the question I have found a fix. Seems it helps questioning others :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it.

First, I have removed the explicit `scanBasePackage` description from `@SpringBootApplication`.
Secondly, I have annotated the configuration file from the library with `@ComponentScan` and created the following file: `resources/META-INF/spring.factories` with the following content:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
    my-library.package.MyLibraryConfig
```

This is my complete library config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyConfig {
...
}
```